# How to ensure a function can't be called twice?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Withing a Phoenix Web App, I have a controller that calls a function to start some processing. This processing might take a significant amount of time.

Currently, if I call the controller twice, this process terminates and is restarted (undesirably).

How can I ensure that subsequent calls to the function don't kill or restart the process and are simply ignored?

Googling seems to suggests using an Agent, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Although I can set the state of a flag to prevent it from being re-run, the process still dies when the controller is called a second time.

Demo of the problem:  https://github.com/corynorris/singleprocess

[image: process failing]

The button on the left works as expected, and uses javascript just to post to an endpoint /start.

The button on the right restarts the process every time its pressed.

**Update:** The POST request, would cancel the previous request, and kill the long running process. The GET request simply couldn't do this, because it was blocking any subsequent requests. The solution here is to run the process separately from the main thread (asynchronously) so that it doesn't die when the post request is cancelled).

In order to do this, I have modified the code to use `GenServer`. I am not sure if this is the correct approach, but I have a working solution with the below changes.

1) I've modified `my_process.ex` to store a process state, and start the work function asyncrhonously (via `Task.async`)

```
  def handle_call(:start, _from, process_map) do
    case Map.get(process_map, :process_running) do
      true ->
        {:reply, process_map, process_map}

      _other ->
        Task.async(&do_work/0)
        updated_process_map = Map.put(process_map, :process_running, true)
        {:reply, updated_process_map, updated_process_map}
    end
  end
```

2) I've implemented `handle_info` to update the status when the `Task.async` completes:

```
def handle_info(_, process_map) do
    updated_process_map = Map.put(process_map, :process_running, false)
    {:noreply, updated_process_map}
  end
```

It broadcasts the status via the channels API:

```
    SingleProcessWeb.Endpoint.broadcast!("room:notification", "new_msg", %{
      uid: 1,
      body: status
    })
```

3) I've updated `application.ex` to start the process once via:

```
children = [
  SingleProcessWeb.Endpoint,
  worker(SingleProcess.MyProcess, [[name: :my_process]])
]
```

I'm not certain if this is the best approach, but it works, so my next steps would be to modify it to be more general and abstract away the process implementation.

Comment: If you go here: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.Spec.html, you will see that the `worker()` syntax for specifying a supervised children is deprecated.  The docs tell you to go read the Supervisor section and here https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#module-child_spec-1 the docs explain why you should use the syntax `{Module.Name, [arg1,arg2]} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I ensure that subsequent calls to the function don't kill or
>   restart the process and are simply ignored?

How about something like:

```
defmodule MyProcess do
  use Agent

  def start_link(_args) do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: :flags)
  end

  def start() do
    #spawn() long running process here
  end

  def running? do
    Agent.get(
      :flags,
      fn(map) -> Map.get(map, :process_running) end
    )
  end

  def set_running_flag do
    Agent.update(
      :flags, 
      fn(map) -> Map.put(map, :process_running, true) end
    )
  end

end
```

Then in your action:

```
  def your_action(conn, _params) do

    if MyProcess.running?() do
      render(this)
    else         
      MyProcess.start()
      MyProcess.set_running_flag()
      render(that)
    end

  end
```

> Although I can set the state of a flag to prevent it from being
>   re-run, the process still dies when the controller is called a second
>   time.

Don't link to the process.

> This processing might take a significant amount of time

Yeah, but do you need to get some reply back from the process, or can the process be started without any further contact?

**Response to comment**:

Here's what I did:

(I revised this some more so that the Agent doesn't ever get killed and to allow a new counter to start when any previous counter has finished.  However, if a counter is broadcasting, then no requests are allowed to start another counter.)

lib/hello/counter.ex

```
defmodule Hello.Counter do

  def start(count) do
    set_counting_flag(true)
    spawn(__MODULE__, :publish_count, [count])
  end

  def publish_count(0) do
    set_counting_flag(false)
  end
  def publish_count(count) do
    Process.sleep 1_000
    HelloWeb.CountChannel.broadcast_count(count)
    publish_count(count-1)
  end

  def is_counting? do
    Agent.get(:my_agent, 
      fn map -> Map.get(map, :counter_running) end
    )
  end

  def set_counting_flag(bool) do
    Agent.update(:my_agent, 
      fn map ->
        Map.update(map, 
                   :counter_running, 
                   bool, 
                   fn _ -> bool end
        )
      end 
    )
  end

end
```

lib/hello/my_agent.ex:

```
defmodule Hello.MyAgent do
  use Agent

  def start_link(_args) do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: :my_agent)
  end

end
```

lib/hello_web/channels/count_channel.ex:

```
defmodule HelloWeb.CountChannel do
  use Phoenix.Channel

  #auth
  def join("count:lobby", _msg, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end
  def join("count:" <> _other, _params, _socket) do
    {:error, %{reason: "unauthorized"}}
  end

  def handle_in("new_msg", %{"body" => body}, socket) do
    broadcast!(socket, "new_msg", %{body: body})
    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  #You can use a Phoenix function to broadcast directly to an Endpoint:
  def broadcast_count(n) do
    HelloWeb.Endpoint.broadcast!("count:lobby", "new_msg", %{body: "#{n}"})
  end

end
```

lib/hello_web/channels/user_socket.ex:

```
defmodule HelloWeb.UserSocket do
  use Phoenix.Socket

  ## Channels
  channel "count:*", HelloWeb.CountChannel

  # Socket params are passed from the client and can
  # be used to verify and authenticate a user. After
  # verification, you can put default assigns into
  # the socket that will be set for all channels, ie
  #
  #     {:ok, assign(socket, :user_id, verified_user_id)}
  #
  # To deny connection, return `:error`.
  #
  # See `Phoenix.Token` documentation for examples in
  # performing token verification on connect.
  def connect(_params, socket, _connect_info) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end

  # Socket id's are topics that allow you to identify all sockets for a given user:
  #
  #     def id(socket), do: "user_socket:#{socket.assigns.user_id}"
  #
  # Would allow you to broadcast a "disconnect" event and terminate
  # all active sockets and channels for a given user:
  #
  #     HelloWeb.Endpoint.broadcast("user_socket:#{user.id}", "disconnect", %{})
  #
  # Returning `nil` makes this socket anonymous.
  def id(_socket), do: nil
end
```

lib/hello_web/router.ex:

```
  ...
  ...
  scope "/", HelloWeb do
    pipe_through :browser

    get "/", PageController, :index
    get "/count/:count", PageController, :counter

  end

  # Other scopes may use custom stacks.
  # scope "/api", HelloWeb do
  #   pipe_through :api
  # end
end
```

lib/hello_web/controllers/page_controller.ex:

```
defmodule HelloWeb.PageController do
  use HelloWeb, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, "index.html")
  end

  def counter(conn, %{"count" => count}) do
    if ! Hello.Counter.is_counting? do
      {int_part, _rest} = Integer.parse(count)
      Hello.Counter.start(int_part)
    end

    render(conn, "index.html")
  end
end
```

hello/assets/js/socket.js:

```
// NOTE: The contents of this file will only be executed if
// you uncomment its entry in "assets/js/app.js".

// To use Phoenix channels, the first step is to import Socket,
// and connect at the socket path in "lib/web/endpoint.ex".
//
// Pass the token on params as below. Or remove it
// from the params if you are not using authentication.
import {Socket} from "phoenix"

let socket = new Socket("/socket", {params: {token: window.userToken}})

// When you connect, you'll often need to authenticate the client.
// For example, imagine you have an authentication plug, `MyAuth`,
// which authenticates the session and assigns a `:current_user`.
// If the current user exists you can assign the user's token in
// the connection for use in the layout.
//
// In your "lib/web/router.ex":
//
//     pipeline :browser do
//       ...
//       plug MyAuth
//       plug :put_user_token
//     end
//
//     defp put_user_token(conn, _) do
//       if current_user = conn.assigns[:current_user] do
//         token = Phoenix.Token.sign(conn, "user socket", current_user.id)
//         assign(conn, :user_token, token)
//       else
//         conn
//       end
//     end
//
// Now you need to pass this token to JavaScript. You can do so
// inside a script tag in "lib/web/templates/layout/app.html.eex":
//
//     <script>window.userToken = "<%= assigns[:user_token] %>";</script>
//
// You will need to verify the user token in the "connect/3" function
// in "lib/web/channels/user_socket.ex":
//
//     def connect(%{"token" => token}, socket, _connect_info) do
//       # max_age: 1209600 is equivalent to two weeks in seconds
//       case Phoenix.Token.verify(socket, "user socket", token, max_age: 1209600) do
//         {:ok, user_id} ->
//           {:ok, assign(socket, :user, user_id)}
//         {:error, reason} ->
//           :error
//       end
//     end
//
// Finally, connect to the socket:
socket.connect()

// Now that you are connected, you can join channels with a topic:
let channel = socket.channel("count:lobby", {})

channel.join()
  .receive("ok", resp => { console.log("Joined successfully", resp) })
  .receive("error", resp => { console.log("Unable to join", resp) })

let text_input_box = document.querySelector("#msg_to_send")
let msg_div = document.querySelector("#received_messages")

text_input_box.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
  let return_key = 13

  if (event.keyCode == return_key) {
    channel.push("new_msg", {body: text_input_box.value})
    text_input_box.value = ""
  }

})

channel.on("new_msg", payload => {
  let new_msg_div = document.createElement('div')
  new_msg_div.innerText = `[${Date()}]: ${payload.body}`
  msg_div.appendChild(new_msg_div)
})

export default socket
```

lib/hello_web/templates/page/index.html

```
<div id="received_messages"></div>
<input id="msg_to_send" type="text"></input>
```

lib/hello/application.ex:

```
defmodule Hello.Application do
  # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    # List all child processes to be supervised
    children = [
      # Start the Ecto repository
      Hello.Repo,

      # Start the endpoint when the application starts
      HelloWeb.Endpoint,

      # Starts a worker by calling: Hello.Worker.start_link(arg)
      # {Hello.Worker, arg},

      Hello.MyAgent  #calls Hello.MyAgent.start_link([])
    ]

    # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Hello.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end

  # Tell Phoenix to update the endpoint configuration
  # whenever the application is updated.
  def config_change(changed, _new, removed) do
    HelloWeb.Endpoint.config_change(changed, removed)
    :ok
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! My _long running process_  just broadcasts a count from 1-100 to a channel. The goal would be to update the user with the real processes status. With your code above, I have the same issue, where-in if I call the action twice, the long running process restarts, and the count goes back to 1 (the desired behavior would be finishing the count to 100). It sounds like _Don't link to the process._ is where I'm going wrong. I've just placed `MyProcess.start_link()` in my `application.ex` as I'm not sure how else to do it (still learning). Any suggestions?

Comment: @cnorris, I got something to work. Check the bottom of my answer.  The counter won't start again unless you kill the server.  I don't quite know why that is.  My intent was to allow the counter to start up again once it had finished counting.

Comment: @cnorris, Okay, I understand now: a process that terminates normally does not cause any linked processes to terminate, i.e. the Agent, rather a process has to crash for its linked processes to terminate, so the Agent continues to exist after the Counter process finishes counting and terminates normally.  To allow another Counter process to begin after the previous Counter process terminates normally, you can do: `def publish_count(0), do: Agent.stop(:count_server) end`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me with this - it was incredibly insightful!